# Checkbox doesnot work when clicked, how can i fix this?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to build a responsive navbar, unforunately the checkbox isn't working. I was following along a youtube video for the navbar. This is my HTML code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #457b9d;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease-out;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}

nav h2 {
  color: white;
}

.fa {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: white;
  color: #3B5998;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: white;
  color: #125688;
}

#social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .menu-btn i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#click {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:940px) {
  nav .menu-btn i {
    display: block;
  }
  #click:checked~nav .menu-btn i::before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    background-color: #457b9d;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #check:checked~ul {
    left: 0%;
  }
  nav ul li {
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav>
  <h2>TRT</h2>


  <ul>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Facilities</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="social">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
    <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>


  </div>
</nav>
```

I don't know how to fix it as I am very new to web development. I did search up some solution but none of them worked. Please help.

Comment: Hi there, can you please explain what should the checkbox do? If you're looking to open the menu after clicking these, you need some Javascript

Comment: Your CSS selectors do not match your HTML .  for instance: `#click:checked~nav` looks for an input with id click standing ahead <nav> , here it is inside. Idem for `#check:checked~ul` it stands inside when the selector looks for it before <ul>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start taking the checkbox outside nav and insert it right before nav so your CSS selectors are efficient.
update then  `#click:checked~ ul` to  `#click:checked~nav ul` to follow the html structure .

example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #457b9d;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease-out;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}

nav h2 {
  color: white;
}

.fa {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: white;
  color: #3B5998;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: white;
  color: #125688;
}

#social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .menu-btn i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#click {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:940px) {
  nav .menu-btn i {
    display: block;
  }
  #click:checked~nav .menu-btn i::before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    background-color: #457b9d;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #click:checked~nav ul {
    left: 0%;
  }
  nav ul li {
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
<nav>
  <h2>TRT</h2>


  <ul>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Facilities</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="social">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>


  </div>
</nav>
```